# does modified function in python decorator has to return a value

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand the behavior of decorator.
I understand that a decorator has to return an object so I can understand the syntax below:

```
def my_deco(fonction):
    print("Deco is called with parameter the function {0}".format(fonction))
    return fonction

@my_deco
def hello():
    print("hello !")
Deco is called with parameter the function <function salut at 0x00BA5198>
```

Here the decorator does not do much, but in the case I need to modify the function, I'd define a decorator like this

```
def my_deco(fonction):
    def modified_func():
        print("Warning ! calling {0}".format(fonction))
        return fonction()
    return modified_func
@my_deco
def hello():
    print("Salut !")
```

The initial function behavior is modified through modified_func.This is fine

It includes the call to the initial function. This is fine

Now what I don't understand is: why do we return the result of the function? in my case the function is a simple 'print' so I don't get why I should return something

Thanks for your explanation

Comment: Because you can apply a decorator to *any* function, and those other functions might well have return values. See also: supporting arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't have to `return fonction()`.  You could instead just invoke it e.g. `fonction()` and discard the result or perhaps under the right circumstances not call `fonction` at all.  It's your decorator so you get to decide what makes sense.  Ask yourself this: should the caller of `fonction` expect a significantly different result if it were decorated?  If the answer is "no" (and it usually is) then the function your decorator returns should probably return `fonction`'s result.

Comment: thanks jq170727 for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

As it is in the comments: usually when you write a decorator, you make it so that it can be used with any possible function. And the way to do that is to return either whatever the original function returned, or transform that return value (which can also be done in the wrapper function).

In Python, all functions actually *do* return something. Functions without an explicit return statement return the value `None`. So, if your wrpper function, inside the decorator, always returns whatever the decorated function returned, it will be on the safe side: even if the decorated function had no explicit return, it will return a `None` that is just forwarded by your wrapper.

Now, that is not "mandatory". If you know beforehand that your decorator will only be applied to functions with no return value, you are free not to put a return statement in the wrapper function as well - it is not an incorrect syntax (but it is likely a trap for your future self).